# Tem como eu desfazer uma análise

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Nessa análise

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/222343

eu vacilei, aprovei um conteúdo que deveria ser rejeitado.

A pergunta era sobre Visual Studio e o operador respondeu sobre o Visual Code.

Minha pergunta é há a possibilidade de reverter minha análise caso venha cometer erros iguais a esse? Ou então o que devo nessa situação?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que é impossível realizar a reversão de uma análise

Comment: @Bacco eu nem deixei em aberto eu aprovei uma resposta ruim. Eu estava pensando em sinalizar novamente a resposta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques atualizei os links. A única coisa a fazer é tomar cuidado nas próximas. Volta e meia a gente se engana, e é por isso que o sistema depende de várias análises (justamente para acomodar enganos). O que não pode é acontecer com frequência desproporcional às analises feitas, pois aí realmente pode gerar uma suspensão da fila. Em princípio, nada que precise se preocupar.